# Changing the icon "type" to "rounded" in Flutter

Tags: flutter, material-ui, icons, themes

I would like to know if there is a way to change the icon "type" in Flutter, not quite sure whats it called but i noticed that Flutter's material icon have different types, for examples:
`Icons.done`, `Icons.done_rounded`, `Icons.done_sharp`

So in this case the type is "rounded" and "sharp", and if i'm not mistaken using `Icons.done` will have a default type of "sharp".

So i was wondering if we can change the default icon type to "rounded", like changing the default icon size using theme data.

Well currently one of the ways is adding the additional `_rounded` to every icon in my Flutter project, but i'm a very lazy person you see. :) Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no default option to set your icons to 'rounded' they are different svg images and have a different name. It is not a setting like icon size.

Check out https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline for the full Icons list.

There are also a lot of 3rd party icon libs on pub.dev. I use https://pub.dev/packages/mdi a lot.